# How to hide filefield url in django Admin

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-admin

Create A image File Field in my model
hide image url or not clickable image name url `Currently: eeee_2020-02-05T100811.271582.txt`
[please refer this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHuCn.png)

Comment: This is kind of a hack, use this if you don't get any proper solution. Add custom CSS for that element and add `color: #fff`. It will hide the url text.

Comment: did you get any solution for this?

Comment: currently unable to find any solution for this problem.